# Spinner Prompt Displays Package Name Instead Of Prompt

Tags: android, android-spinner

This is a weird problem I am facing. The data comes from the SQLite database. It displays package name: `com.dzinesunlimited.foodzines.free.Administration.Menu.MenuAdministrationActivity` instead of "*CHOOSE A CATEGORY*" (Defined in the `strings.xml`). The Spinner is defined in the XML:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnDishCategory"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
    android:popupBackground="@color/panel_medium"
    android:prompt="@string/menu_admin_category_spinner_prompt" >
</Spinner>
```

This is the Java code:

```
MenuAdministratorCategoryAdapter adapMenuCategories = new MenuAdministratorCategoryAdapter(
    getActivity(), 
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
    arrMenuCategory);

spnDishCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View v, int position, long id) {

        if (position != -0) {
            String strMenucategory = arrMenuCategory.get(position).getCatID();
            SELECTED_CATEGORY_ID = strMenucategory;
            Log.e("CAT ID", SELECTED_CATEGORY_ID);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            /** CLEAR THE CURRENT GRIDVIEW AND THE ARRAYADAPTER **/
            gridDishes.invalidate();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            arrDishes.clear();

            /** CHANGE THE PROMPT **/
            spnDishCategory.setPrompt(arrMenuCategory.get(position).getCatName());

            /** FETCH THE MENUS IN THE SELECTED CATEGORY **/
            new fetchMenusInTheCategory().execute();

            /* INSTANTIATE THE ADAPTER */
            adapter = new MenuAdministrationAdapter(getActivity(), arrDishes);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

    }
});
```

This is the `AsyncTask` that fetches the data from the database:

```
private class loadMenuCategories extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>    {

    /** AN INTEGER INSTANCE TO HOLD THE TOTAL NUMBER OF ITEMS RETURNED BY THE DATABASE **/
    int intMenuCategories;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        // CONSTRUCT THE QUERY TO FETCH ALL TWEETS FROM THE DATABASE
        String strQueryData = "SELECT * FROM categories";

        // CAST THE QUERY IN THE CURSOR TO FETCH THE RESULTS
        cursor = db.selectAllData(strQueryData);
        intMenuCategories = cursor.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        if (intMenuCategories > 0)  {

            if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() != 0)   {

                /* AN INSTANCE OF THE MenuAdministratorCategoryData HELPER CLASS */
                MenuAdministratorCategoryData menuCategory;

                for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {

                    /***** INSTANTIATE THE MenuAdministratorCategoryData INSTANCE "menuCategory" *****/
                    menuCategory = new MenuAdministratorCategoryData();

                    /** GET THE CATEGORY ID **/
                    if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(db.CATEGORY_ID)) != null)    {
                        String strCatID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(db.CATEGORY_ID));
                        menuCategory.setCatID(strCatID);
                    } else {
                        String strCatID = null;
                        menuCategory.setCatID(strCatID);
                    }

                    /** GET THE CATEGORY NAME **/
                    if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(db.CATEGORY_NAME)) != null)  {
                        String strCatName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(db.CATEGORY_NAME));
                        menuCategory.setCatName(strCatName);
                    } else {
                        String strCatName = null;
                        menuCategory.setCatName(strCatName);
                    }

                    /** ADD THE COLLECTED DATA TO THE ARRAYLIST **/
                    arrMenuCategory.add(menuCategory);
                }
            }

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // CLOSE THE CURSOR
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())   {
            cursor.close();
        }

        // CLOSE THE DATABASE
        db.close();

        // SET THE ADAPTER TO THE GRIDVIEW
        spnDishCategory.setAdapter(adapMenuCategories);

        new showDefaultMenuCategory().execute();
    }

}
```

This is the adapter:

```
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;

    if (row == null)    {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment_category_spn_row, parent, false);
    }

    TextView txtCategoryCode = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtCategoryCode);
    Typeface fntCategoryCode = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf");
    txtCategoryCode.setTypeface(fntCategoryCode);

    /** SET THE CATEGORY NAME **/
    String strCatName = arrMenuCategory.get(position).getCatName();
    if (strCatName != null) {
        txtCategoryCode.setText(strCatName);
    }

    return row;
}
```

How it looks:
[image]

Any help is appreciated helping me fix this problem.

P.S.: If any other code is needed, please let me know.

**EDIT**: Almost forgot. This is a custom Spinner. The custom layout for the row is:

**menu_fragment_category_spn_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/txtCategoryCode"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="#ff171717"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="11dp"
    android:text="INVENTORY CATEGORY CODE"
    android:textColor="#F9F9F9"
    android:textSize="18sp" >

</TextView>
```

Comment: did you try adding the text to the text view directly. without using any Strings. like this: android:text = "choose a category"

Comment: @HassaanRabbani: I'm afraid that is not an option. The `Spinner` widget does not have the `android:text=""` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is to late, but maybe this answer can help to any other developers facing this problem.

Just override getView method in your adapter with same implementation as your drop down view:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```